# Calling a list of DataFrame index with index key value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[3,3,3]]*4,index=['a','b','c','d'])
```

While we can extract a copy of a section of an index via specifying row numbers like below:
    i1=df.index[1:3].copy()

Unfortunately we can't extract a copy of a section of an index via specifying the key (like the case of df.loc method). When I try the below:

```
i2=df.index['a':'c'].copy()
```

I get the below error:

```
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

Is there any alternative to call a subset of an index based on its keys? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `.loc`, see this [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-label):

```
i2 = df.loc['a':'c'].index
print(i2)
```

Output:

```
Index(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='object')
```

or

```
df.loc['a':'c'].index.tolist()
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: This seems to be an irrelevant comment as this has nothing to do with the index of the df.

Comment: My bad. Re-thinking your solution for a while, it is actually a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

Simpliest is [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with `index`:

```
i1 = df.loc['b':'c'].index
print (i1)
Index(['b', 'c'], dtype='object')
```

Or is possible use [`get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) for positions:

```
i1 = df.index

i1 = i1[i1.get_loc('b') : i1.get_loc('d') + 1]
print (i1)
Index(['b', 'c'], dtype='object')
```

---

```
i1 = i1[i1.get_loc('b') : i1.get_loc('d') + 1]
print (i1)
Index(['b', 'c', 'd'], dtype='object')
```

Alternative:

```
i1 = i1[i1.searchsorted('b') : i1.searchsorted('d') + 1]
print (i1)
Index(['b', 'c', 'd'], dtype='object')
```